# Backbone history appends route to URL twice

Tags: backbone.js, history, jekyll, router

This is a followup to my earlier question, [Backbone routing/history issue with Jekyll static pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559179/backbone-routing-history-issue-with-jekyll-static-pages).

I'm building a simple, static site with Jekyll and using Backbone to do some routing. All of my pages are separate HTML files. I handle navigation by watching my `<a>` elements for clicks,  and using `jQuery.get` to load up the new page and replace the content. A bit unusual, I know, but I want a single page in order to provide smooth transitions and preserve my webfonts.

The issue is that when I start from any page other than my root url — let's say `/page1` — navigate around, and then use the browser's back button to return to my first page, I get a 404: `/page1/page1 not found`. Here's some example navigation:

```
localhost/page1/  <- entered into address bar
localhost/page2   <- linked from an <a>
localhost/page1   <- linked from an <a>
localhost/page3   <- linked from an <a>
localhost/page1   <- clicked back button; works fine
localhost/page2   <- clicked back button; works fine
localhost/page1/  <- clicked back button; 404 at /page1/page1
```

Note that returning to `page1` from deeper within the history works fine; it's only my starting route that gives me grief. I think it might have to do with the trailing slash appended by the browser when I manually enter that first URL, but I'm not sure how to resolve this.

I posted my relevant backbone code in [this JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/d54BC/). As you can see, my router is initialized with `silent: true` and `root: '/'`.

Not sure what to do here — been banging my head against the wall for weeks!